# App Engine cron schedule to run on weekdays

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I want to run a cron on App Engine every 5 minutes, but only on weekdays.

```
cron:
- description: run 
  url: /cron/run
  schedule: */5 * * * 1-5
```

It gives the error:

> expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found '/'

Comment: That doesn't seem to match the syntax specified in the [schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format), but I'm not sure it will be possible (you would need something like `every 5 minutes every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri` but I think only 1 `every` is allowed).  Could you put a day-of-week check in the cron handler?

Comment: You can't. Consider checking if its right time to run inside of your code, or use Task Queue instead of cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible just using cron. If what you want is saving instance hours, you can instead schedule a chron to run at midnight daily. It checks if its a weekday and if so it runs a taskqueue. The taskqueue starts another taskqueue 5 minutes ahead and also does its work. Taskqueue stops as soon as day changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was here to find out how to run a cron on a specific time on Weekdays,

```
  schedule: every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 7:00
```

This worked for me, but if you want to specify both date period and the time period, you have to use Zig Mandel's solution. Hope it helps.